# Windows Store App - Diagnose/Debug Printing Issue (PrintTaskCompletion.Failed)

Tags: debugging, printing, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to debug/find documentation on how to diagnose a printing issue in a Windows Store App I'm building.  I've looked at several examples of "how to print in WinRT/Windows Store Apps" and have included the common bit of error checking code in the Completed handler below:

```
//inside the handler passed as the second parameter into CreatePrintTask
printTask.Completed += async (s, e) =>
{
    //Reset all of our internal variables (code omitted)

    if (e.Completion == PrintTaskCompletion.Failed)
    {
        await Execute.OnUiThreadAsync(async () =>
        {
            //Log Error and Show a Friendly Message to the user (code omitted)
            /*HELP - Is there anything else in the parameters passed in to the Completed event
              handler that can help specify the error?  The only thing it has is the Completion
              property; I can't seem to find any other useful data.*/

        });
    }
};
```

My code is getting inside the `PrintTaskCompletion.Failed` bit, which is great that the error is being handled, but now I need to know why it's failing to try to debug the issue.  I've been stuck on this for a while and haven't found any useful posts/articles/books saying how to get more information about the error that occurred so I can try to fix the issue.

If more code is needed (a lot was omitted for brevity), please let me know.  And of course, please ask any clarifying questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, This isn't an answer but it may be helpful. I've been looking at the source code and the only way I can see to get error information is to handle the IPrintDocumentPackageStatusEvent. Unfortunately I can't see any way to register for this event from a managed print task. If you are using D2D to print you can register for this event when you create your document package. I hope this helps. -James

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why my error was happening.  I had a very subtle bug that ultimately was leading to no actual content getting added to the `PrintDocumentSource` in the `PrintDocument.AddPages` handler, which  was causing my error.

As soon as I fixed that bug, it began to work as expected.

Thank, you, James, for providing a possible solution!